# Debugging .Net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I built a .net web app using visual studio.  I tested it in visual studio and it seemed to work fine.  After publishing it locally and copying to my remote web server it seems to keep crashing the application pool and I'm not sure how to debug it.

**How I published it:**  I published it locally and copied all the files to: wwwroot/ss/  on the remote server.  After that, I installed the folder as an application in IIS.  Because it was built using version .net 4.5 framework but I only had .net 4.0 application pools I did:

appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: api /managedRuntimeVersion:4.5

Now, anytime I go to the application using my url: mywebsite.com/ss/api/controller/param, I get a 503 service unavailable.

When I check the application pool after I go to that URL, the app pool has been shut down.  I tried using try/catches, but it doesn't seem to help.  All I see in the log file is:

2015-03-09 01:01:39 remoteIP 14132 siteIP 80 HTTP/1.1 GET /ss/api/controller/param 503 4 AppOffline api

What's the best way to debug this?  Can I use a remote debugger?  Is there any folder besides C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR or logs/LogFiles folder in the site root where I can find more information about why it crashed?

**EDIT:**
If it is at all useful, I see in the event log:

I see several warnings:
A process serving application pool 'api' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '2724'. The process exit code was '0xfffffffe'.

followed by:
Application pool 'api' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: If you really suspect an issue with a crashing application pool I would look at installing DebugDiag (http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40336) on the server and setting it up to trap exceptions from w3wp.exe.

Comment: Can you browse the Web API locally, within the server? Please ensure that the IIS is running on 64 bit machine.

Comment: When publishing, do you have the precompile checkbox checked or unchecked?

Comment: Also check the event log for more information.  Sometimes that helps.

Comment: @womp I installed DebugDiag -- I don't see any messages when I attach it to my pool and the pool shuts down.  Does that mean it isn't a crash but some other behavior causing the pool to stop?

Comment: @TejSoft it is running on a 64 bit machine and I can browse to it locally

Comment: @James Laruk -- I did not.  But I tried clicking it and re-publishing and all, it did not help.

Comment: @DWright -- the event log says: Application pool 'api' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: Are you developing a 64 or 32bit target?  if 32bit target, is your pool set to allow 32 bit?  One possibility, although it has security ramifications, you could install VS on the server and enable first chance exception debugging.  Make sure to note that and how you did this, so you'll know how to turn it off again.

Comment: Can you disable the app pool and create a new one just for the API? Assign only the API site to this app pool. Also check what Microsoft says about the resolution: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc735202(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Dwight -- I'm building for "Any CPU" and I have Enable 32-bit applications set to false.  I tried setting to true with no success.

Comment: @Tejsoft App Pool 'api' is already only being used by this application.  I read through that, but it doesn't seem to provide a solution.

Comment: It might be possible that the API you have developed is throwing errors which are unhandled exceptions. Can you create a test API (new project) with just a 'hello world' JSON response and try to browse it? Check this solution: http://geekswithblogs.net/VBTips/archive/2011/09/30/application-pool-crashing-issue.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as the .net 4.5 run time. Set it back to .net 4.0

```
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name: api /managedRuntimeVersion:4.0
```

Fun fact.

There are only 3 .net runtimes as of 2015-03-09

- .net runtime 1.0
- .net runtime 2.0
- .net runtime 4.0

These runtimes allow you to run the following (ignoring the various SP)

- .net runtime 1.0

  - .net framework 1.0
- .net runtime 2.0

  - .net framework 2.0
  - .net framework 3.0
  - .net framework 3.5
- .net runtime 4.0

  - .net framework 4.0
  - .net framework 4.5
  - .net framework 4.5.1
  - .net framework 4.5.2